# Removing duplicates in Lithium/Freemarker

Tags: freemarker, duplicates

I am using Lithium custom components to create a list of users who have written the most Blog articles. I have a list of users who have written a blog article and then made a rest call to get the number of Blog articles each of those users has written.

```
<#assign authors = rest("blogs/id/audiofile/posts")>

<#list authors.node_message_context.message.author as t>
<#assign count = rest("${t.@href}/posts/style/blog/count")>
<#assign orderedCount = count.value>
<#list orderedCount as c>
<ul>
<li>Blog posts ${c} userid ${t.@href}
</ul>
</#list>
</#list>
```

Gives an output of

```
Blog posts 4 userid /users/id/2477

Blog posts 4 userid /users/id/2477

Blog posts 4 userid /users/id/2477
```

My question is how do I remove the duplicate authors in this list?

Answer (score 3):

@Wolfgang Fahl wish we could modify the Lithium REST APIs =)!

Unfortunately this is not the case, so we have to deal with what we get, that could be doing something like that:

```
<#-- this variable we need to store unique author ids -->
<#assign authorids = [] />
<#-- I'd use API v2 here, think for such stuff it's more powerful than v1 -->
<#assign query = 'SELECT author FROM messages WHERE conversation.style = "blog" AND board.id = "audiofiles"'?url />
<#assign response = rest("2.0", "/search?q=" + query) />

<#-- the response object will contain a list of blog post authors,
     we loop trough them to get uniqe ids of every user that has written
     a blog post, we need them later -->
<#list response.data.items as author>
    <#-- make sure each author just gets added once -->
    <#if !authorids?seq_contains(author.id)>
        <#assign authorids = authorids + [author.id] />
    </#if>
</#list>

<#-- now we loop trough the unique author ids and ask for the amount of
     blog posts they have written -->
<ul>
<#list authorids as id>
    <#assign query = 'SELECT count(*) FROM messages WHERE author.id = id AND board.id = "audiofiles"'?url />
    <#assign response = rest("2.0", "/search?q=" + query) />

    <li>User with ID ${id} has written ${response.data.count} blog posts</li>
</#list>
</ul>
```

Code is untested, so not 100% sure if it works, but I hope the approach I'd choose became clear with the code above...

Answer (score 0):

The faq article 
http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_modify_seq_and_map
outlines why this is tricky. Basically it calls for modifying your restful interface to do the work for you:

```
<#assign authors = rest("blogs/id/audiofile/uniquauthors")>
```

would be an example for a new restful interface and then the work is done on the server side.